# php variable in codebird

Tags: php, twitter

I am using codebird to auto tweet to twitter.
I am OK with tweeting, as below:

```
require_once ('src/codebird.php');
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey('YOURKEY', 'YOURSECRET');

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken('YOURTOKEN', 'YOURTOKENSECRET');

$reply = $cb->statuses_update('status=Whohoo, I just tweeted! today is 01/01/14');
```

How can I add PHP $ variable to the tweet, I tried: (not working)

```
    $todaydte = gmdate("Y-m-d", time());
$reply = $cb->statuses_update('status=Whohoo, I just tweeted! today is $todaydte');
```

it is tweeting (Whohoo, I just tweeted! today is $todaydte) !! 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP strings documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

With single quotes you're specifying a string literal, which won't be processed at all by PHP. You could use double quotes and curly braces, or [sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf).

Comment: I tried to VOTE for you, but they did not allow me, as I am new here.

Answer (score 1):

Just do that:

```
$reply = $cb->statuses_update("status=Whohoo, I just tweeted! today is {$todaydte}");
```

- Double quotes
- And braces (for greater safety)

The result is `"Lorem ipsum {$your_var}"`

Comment: Thanks patrick for your help, but I tried Debso 's way first, and it worked. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: @BASSEL No problem my friend.